# In ArcMap, what is the difference between Copy Parallel and Buffer?

Tags: arcmap, geometry, buffer

To build an offset of a linear feature in ArcMap, what is the difference between Copy Parallel and Buffer?  In terms of the resulting features and their linear differences from the source linear feature?

I am building an easement of a centerline feature.  I want to build a feature that is 25feet either side of my linear feature.  Where the centerline is going without direction changes there seems to be no difference.  Where the centerline changes direction the differences start to appear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

buffer will take the original line to the buffered distance.

[image]

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000

copy parallel has Beveled, Mitered, Rounded Options

[image]

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m700000028000000

Comment: I guess my question is more along the lines of which tool is the correct tool for finding distances offset from a line.  With point of intersections in mind.

Comment: then use the buffer route.

Comment: With the mitered option, at the corner the distance seems to not be correct.  It seems to be more than my given value.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess my question is more along the lines of which tool is the
>   correct tool for finding distances offset from a line. With point of
>   intersections in mind. – Justin 31 mins ago

then I guess, you'll prefer the **buffer** option

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the trace tool with an offset. That might work well for creating an easement off of a centerline. The trace tool is one of my favorites to draw with as I'm often drafting based on other existing features. [image]